# Are multiple NavigationStacks allowed in SwiftUI for nested navigation scenarios while utilizing .toolbar modifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, toolbar, swiftui-navigationstack

I am working on a SwiftUI application where I have a list of items on the main screen. When an item is selected, it navigates to a detailed view of that item. On this detailed view, there are other clickable elements that should navigate to other views. Initially, I thought of wrapping each view in a NavigationStack to manage the navigation and take advantage of the possibility to use .toolbar. However, I do expect that using multiple NavigationStacks may not be a good practice and could lead to a confusing navigation hierarchy and potential performance issues.

Here's a simplified version of my current structure:

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                // Toolbar items for MainView
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text(item.description)
                NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView()) {
                    Text("Go Further")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                // Toolbar items for DetailView
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a recommended way to manage multi-level navigation in SwiftUI, utilize the .toolbar modifier, and adhere to good practices? Any examples or resources on this would be greatly appreciated.

I have come across alternatives like using a single NavigationStack or TabView, but I am unsure how to apply these to maintain a clean, navigable structure, especially when the navigation hierarchy becomes more complex, while still being able to utilize the .toolbar modifier effectively.

Comment: No, just a single stack, there are few exceptions like TabView and modals